# Is there only/except filter available for the observer in ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, activemodel

I am trying to generate `Notification` for `Message` and `Task` in my project. I am using `Mongoid 2`.

I created a `NotificationObserver`, is it possible in this observer to observe `Message` for only `after_create` and observe `Task` for both `after_create` and `after_update`. Like this described here: http://jamesgolick.com/2009/8/5/observational-better-observers-for-activerecord.html

It has been a long time so I think it might be out of the box now, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use two different observers for different classes that will be easy to handle and you can capture the callbacks accordingly

or try this

```
class NotificationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   observe :task, :message

   def after_create(record)
      if record.class == Task
         do task stuff
      else
         do message stuff
      end
   end

   def after_update(record)
      if record.class == Task
         do task stuff
      end
   end
end
```